# Frequency and damping estimation with Prony method?

Tags: frequency, estimation, time-frequency

I have a sinusoidal time domain signal with few damped exponential components.
i.e.

```
fn=[0.4 0.6 1.0];E=[0.03 0.05 0.1];A=[1.0 2.0 3.0];
wn=2*pi.*fn;a=E.*wn;wd=wn.*sqrt(1-E.^2); 
x=A(1)*exp(-a(1)*t).*sin(wd(1)*t)+A(2)*exp(-a(2)*t).*...
sin(wd(2)*t)+A(3)*exp(-a(3)*t).*sin(wd(3)*t);
```

How can I extract the damping ratios and frequency components of this signal by **Prony** method.

*Your help is much appreciated.*

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search reveals the [Prony Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3955-prony-toolbox) on Mathworks file exchange.

Comment: I have a time-domain signal and want to extract its damping and frequency components.I don't know who to use this toolbox, any help? @Phonon

Comment: @Electricman Without running the toolbox. I looked at the thumbnail for it on file exchange. On the left there is a results box with mode, amplitude and damping freq. I guess that it what you want? Have you tried running the demo in the toolbox and working out how to use it?

Comment: @nivag Yes I just saw it extracts the damping too.I've tried to to install this toolbox. but at the first step I don't know how to import the time-domain signal in it.lol let me know if you get the hang of it.